# Poorly assessed quality of a question's title

Tags: discussion

I posted the question [Status code not retained in response on re-throw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78051807/status-code-not-reatined-in-response-on-re-throw) and it went as supposed to. However, for some (to me really weird) reason, the original title wasn't approved. I got an error message both at the initial point of posting and afterward, when I attempted to cheat around it and change the name.

[image]

Linguistically, *not reatained* and *lost* are semantically equivalent, stylistically better with the latter one. Is that an AI going poof here or what am I missing regarding the formulation of the title?

Comment: It's not AI that checks the title, it's very simple Regex, and there are *many* ways to get around it.

Comment: @ThomA I question that regex.   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944)

Comment: "*Linguistically, not reatained and lost are semantically equivalent, stylistically better with the latter one.*" however, the former one makes the titles be longer than 40 characters, which avoids the check altogether.  https://regex101.com/r/eaQllu/1

Comment: TL;DR: your initial title was <=40 characters long, and had the word "code" in it, triggering the error.

Comment: @VLAZ Interesting... I've been using SO since 2012 and **never** had that one popout on me... Glad to see that I'm not alone in my aversion towards that limitations. It's as useful as a ventilation hatch on a submarine... Thanks for the link.

Comment: Please [put more effort into](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) debugging the code before asking a question. Per the comments, the problem is that the reraised exception isn't actually caught locally, so your code reuse scheme is defeated. You would have realized the problem if you had actually used a debugger to verify the control flow. If you're about to post something like "I can't understand why it happens, let alone, how to resolve it." on Stack Overflow, the right process starts with the debugger and ends with an MRE and an explanation of what you learned from debugging.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thank you for pointing out the obvious while incorrectly assuming lack of effort. It sounds like you never get confused, investing a large number of hours. My congratulations. Regrettably, I'm not a super-human and I will occasionally get hopelessly stuck, unable to realize what to someone else may be obvious. Feel free to call me dumb (it's nothing I control). But, kindly please, do not take the liberty to assume lack of effort. Just because you mistakenly believe so, it doesn't make it true. Your comment wasn't useful nor constructive.

Comment: I didn't say anything about anything being obvious. Debuggers exist exactly because we are human, and thus things that we'd like to think "should be obvious", aren't in practice.

Comment: Is the misspelling *[reatained](https://pmortensen.eu/world/EditOverflow.php?LookUpTerm=reatained)* intentional?

Comment: @PeterMortensen The title was incorrectly spelled at the time of posting the question. Then, I noticed the typo and corrected the title, while the URL never updated. The title is correctly spelled since then. (For a brief period, someone had change the title entirely, which in my opinion wasn't an improvement nor eloquent expression. That's been corrected back to the proper and correctly spelled version.) Good eyes, mate, BTW. How did you notice that?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You did post a link named "put more effort into". You **still** keep talking about the importance of debugging. I'm inferring that you are confused as to whether I spent quite some time in the debug mode trying to figure it out. So, your expectation of using a debugger (which I did extensively like an experience dev always does) as a tool to make the issue more obvious isn't relevant in this case. If anything, your remark should be made on the question itself not here (which someone with your rep should know). Or simply refrain from posting it totally as it's not constructive.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Also, the issue of your remark isn't really relevant to the topic here nor is it useful for the general audience. I recommend that we drop it and learn from the experience. I'm inclined not to respond anymore but I don't want you to feel ignored. I do respect your opinion and effort. (I just disagree with this particular instance.)